# Is it possible to update an iframe created by a Chrome Extension content script?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have successfully created a toolbar Chrome Extension that, when a page is loaded, adds buttons and other content. These buttons can interact with the main page.

What I can't do is update those buttons when I change the state of my Extension - from the popup, for instance.

If background.js knows that a change has happened, can it communicate to the content script to tell it to update the iframe? Without updating the parent page on which it sits?

My content scripts are added to every iframe on page...so there are often 4 or 5 versions of content.js on a given page.

Any high-level guidance deeply appreciated.

Of course the user can just refresh the entire page to get the changes...but I'd prefer to have the iframe toolbar update without the user having to take that additional step.

Answer (score 0):

You can message through background.js to reach the content script...

Then do the following in the content script when receiving a message from background.js:

```
$('#iframeID').attr('src', $('#annotatePROsidebar').attr('src'));
```